# How to use `omitempty` with protobuf Timestamp in Golang

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, marshalling, proto

I have an optional field on my struct called `ExpireTime`. It has a `time.Time` type and a `json:"expire_time,omitempty"` tag to not send it, when it is empty. This part works perfectly fine.

When I want to use the same field via GRPC, I run into an issue when converting it to the [protobuf timestamp format](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb).

```
type Timestamp struct {

    // Represents seconds of UTC time since Unix epoch
    // 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Must be from 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z to
    // 9999-12-31T23:59:59Z inclusive.
    Seconds int64 `protobuf:"varint,1,opt,name=seconds,proto3" json:"seconds,omitempty"`
    // Non-negative fractions of a second at nanosecond resolution. Negative
    // second values with fractions must still have non-negative nanos values
    // that count forward in time. Must be from 0 to 999,999,999
    // inclusive.
    Nanos int32 `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=nanos,proto3" json:"nanos,omitempty"`
    // contains filtered or unexported fields
}
```

```
ExpireTime *timestamppb.Timestamp `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=expire_time,json=expireTime,proto3" json:"expire_time,omitempty"`
```

The issue is that an empty `time.Time{}` object will be converted to a negative `seconds` value corresponding to 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z. Having the `omitEmpty` flag will not be applied in this case as the value is not zeroed out. What could I do to omit this field, when it is actually empty? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say `time.Time{}` converts to `0001-01-01T00:00:00Z`; this [is working as intended](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/710). Note that you also need to be careful converting in the [opposite direction](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/990) (a zero `TimeStamp` will become `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`).

However generally the `Timestamp` will be part of a message, for example:

```protobuf
message MyMessage{
   google.protobuf.Timestamp  comm_time = 1;
}
```

Running this through `protoc` will result in something like:

```golang
type MyMessage struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    CommTime *timestamppb.Timestamp `protobuf:"bytes, 1,opt,name=comm_time,json=commTime,proto3" json:"comm_time,omitempty"`
}
```

This means you should be able to achieve the result you are looking for with `CommTime=nil`; e.g.

```golang
sourceTime := time.Time{}  // Whatever time you want to encode
var commTime *timestamp.Timestamp
if !sourceTime.IsZero() {
        commTime = timestamppb.New(sourceTime)
}

msg := MyMessage{
   CommTime: commTime,
}
```